# Alternative to boxplot

Tags: data-visualization

So I have some data that would be obvious to be used in a boxplot. However, I tend to think boxplots are quite boring, and not very drawing - visualization wise at least.

So basically my data would follow the same idea as:

[image]

So I just wanted to ask if there were a more beautiful way of presenting data as this without using boxplots. Again, something that draws the reader a bit more.

Comment: Well, I think they mostly try to explain why boxplots aren't that difficult to look at. Imo that doesn't have much to do with visualization. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: If you are unsatisfied with all the 7 answers in the marked duplicate, please edit your question and explain why you are unsatisfied, so that your question stands out clearly as different. If so, it can be reopened.

Comment: Some other (near)-dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240582/alternative-to-boxplots-that-illustrate-mean,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/is-there-a-boxplot-variant-for-poisson-distributed-data/13429#13429,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13875/boxplot-for-several-distributions,